# PHP ООП. Как получить доступ к свойству "соседнего" объекта?

Tags: php

В php что-то подобное в принципе возможно?

```
<?php

class A{
    public $hi = "hello world";
}

class B{
    function __construct(){
        echo "$objA->hi";
    }
}

$objA = new A();
$objB = new B();
?>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Называется это dependency injection (внедрение зависимостей):

- https://designpatternsphp.readthedocs.io/ru/latest/Structural/DependencyInjection/README.html
- https://tyapk.ru/blog/post/dependency-injection-and-service-container
- https://symfony.ru/doc/current/components/dependency_injection.html

---

```
class A {
    public $hi = "hello world";
}

class B {
    function __construct(A $objA){
        echo $objA->hi;
    }
}
    
$objA = new A();
$objB = new B($objA);
```

Comment: @Эдуард да можно и оставить) Но убрал)

Comment: Спасибо большое, вы мне очень помогли)